# How to change value of annotation of field on runtime in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I need to change (or remove whole) annotation value on runtime from one class. I got the exapmles from SO but this solution works only for class annotations, not for the field annotations. Any idea how to get this done? Thre reason for this is to make minor change in DB model definition classes to not use `enum` fields as inmemory db's not having this data type like MySQL does.

Here is working(partially) solution found on SO:

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;

public class AnnotationModification2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Something annotation = (Something) Foobar.class.getAnnotations()[0];
        System.out.println("oldAnnotation = " + Foobar.class.getAnnotation(Something.class).someProperty());
        changeAnnotationValue(annotation, "someProperty", "another value");
        System.out.println("modifiedAnnotation = " + Foobar.class.getAnnotation(Something.class).someProperty());

        annotation = (Something) Foobar.class.getDeclaredField("name").getAnnotations()[0];

        System.out.println("oldAnnotation = " + annotation.someProperty());
        changeAnnotationValue(annotation, "someProperty", "another value");
        System.out.println("modifiedAnnotation = " + annotation.someProperty());

        System.out.println(Foobar.class.getDeclaredField("name").getAnnotation(Something.class).someProperty());
    }

    /**
     * Changes the annotation value for the given key of the given annotation to newValue and returns
     * the previous value.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Object changeAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String key, Object newValue){
        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field f;
        try {
            f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        Object oldValue = memberValues.get(key);
        if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != newValue.getClass()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        memberValues.put(key,newValue);
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Something(someProperty = "some value")
    public static class Foobar {

        @Something(someProperty = "Old field value!")
        private String name;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Something {

        String someProperty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "getField" method:

```
Something annotation = (Something) Foobar.class.getField("name").getAnnotations()[0];
```